# Data only plan on Motorola Atrix 4G?

Tags: sim-card, motorola-atrix-4g

I finally made the switch from iPhone to Android.  So far it has been quite nice
with the Atrix.

I got the phone with the intent of having 3G data and WIFI only, no voice or SMS.

I got a data only service from a company called FOMA, installed the SIM and the phone comes up with:

SIM not provisioned MM#2

Google searches say the SIM is bad, but that is not the case for me.  Here is what I have
been able to test:

1. SIM from another carrier in Atrix that has voice service - OK
2. FOMA SIM in a Blackberry, Blackberry comes up OK and recognizes the network

The provider says the SIM is active, which makes sense since it works in my Blackberry.

If I go into the network setup the phone can see the two major providers here, but can't
operate on either of them.

Is it possible the phone is saying the SIM is not provisioned because there is no voice
service available?

Anyone know how I can go about debugging the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would talk to FOMA.  I once got a data-only SIM from T-Mobile and my phone worked for a couple days, but then they disabled the SIM because they don't allow Android phones to be used without voice.  It's pretty stupid, but that might be the situation in your case as well.